# Use .getWindow() in Application-file

Tags: java, android, kotlin

This may be a silly question but I have the following situation: I want to setup my window layout every time the app is open, for example changing the status bar color. So I created my Application file because I heard it is better if you check something like this in the application file and not in the MainActivity.

**Problem:** How can I call the getWindow() method without an open activity.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

A bit tricky, but you can use Window manager in background-service to display your views without opening an Activity.

Also, for API Level 26+ (Oreo or above) you have to start your service as foreground service

Comment: First off, thank you but now I have another question: Do you know any method, that is better than this one?